# Incorrect behaviour for some browsers with django-registration sign up flow

Tags: django, django-registration

I'm receiving reports of several users running into issues with a django-registration sign up flow.  I'm not able to reproduce it, and I believe it's just happening for certain browsers.

The problem happens when they follow the email activation link.  Although the database shows they have successfully activated their email, they see the page that says that the link has expired.  It's as if they visited the activation page already and then are seeing it for the second time.  Initially I thought this was user error, but several users have reported it, which makes me think there is something else up.

One user has reported it working in Firefox, but not Safari, on a desktop - and not working on iPad or iPhone.

I have used django-registration a lot so I'm surprised by this bug and am drawing blanks about what it might be down to.  Anyone have any ideas?

PS This is also happening with the same site, perhaps related: [Django messages faulty, but only on one particular network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26934278/django-messages-not-going-away-on-some-browsers)

Comment: What makes you think that the problem is browser related?

Comment: I think it's a client-side issue because one user has reported it as working in Firefox, but not Safari.  And I have been unable to reproduce it myself.

Comment: Never trust users ;) Did you try yourself with Safari? If you have no Mac, you can use http://www.browserstack.com/

Comment: yes I hear you! I haven't tested on safari, but I've got others to who have told me it's working. Yet still there have been several independent reports from users of the problem. I guess I'll have to go through the different machines on browserstack and see if I can break it!